# Where were they ecoshapping and were condemned by the UN

Tags: native-americans, united-nations, ecology

I remember an article about an North American Indian tribe that sank an iron rich ship in their lake or inlet to the ocean in order to increase the amount of fish. I think the UN sanctioned them or condemned or something. I tried to find what was going on with that and how they were treated by the UN and I was unable.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/10/19/science/earth/iron-dumping-experiment-in-pacific-alarms-marine-experts.html?_r=0) what you were thinking of?

Comment: maybe thats really simular...and my memory from 2 years would be that distorted... @Comintern thanks i appreciate it ....

Comment: LOL he was successful

Comment: yeah thats it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russ_George